# Enquire.js seems not to work with Vue.js version 2.0

Tags: javascript, vue.js, enquire.js

I want to use Enquire.js in my Vue.js(v 2.0) project. There are a bunch of examples on the internet where users integrating Enquire with Vue.js. 
For example here: https://jsfiddle.net/Linusborg/843dk9zs/

When I integrate Enquire.js in my Vue.js/webpack project it doesn't work and gave no error messages at all in the console. I don't know exactly what I'm doing wrong here.

This is my code, located in main.js My root file for the application.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Enquire from 'enquire.js' //installed using NPM
require('./stylesheet.css')

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    displayIsLarge: false,
    displayIsSmall: true
  },
  ready: function() {
    var self = this;
    // Listen for changes in the browser's size
    enquire.register("screen and (max-width:400px)", {
      match: function() {
        self.displayIsSmall = true;
        console.log("the screen is now small");
      },
      unmatch: function() {
        self.displayIsLarge = true;
        console.log("the screen is now large");
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: `ready` has been replaced by `mounted` in Vue2

Comment: Thankyou for your comment Abdel Rhman. I've changed ready with mounted with succes! My browser inspector console now returns an error, enquire is not defined. I'm now a step further and have to fix why enquire.js isn't properly loaded in my webpack project.

Comment: can you put that error.

Comment: Enquire.js is not defined: Uncaught ReferenceError: enquire is not defined

Comment: I have just loaded enquire.js without loading it via webpack / node modules. When I load my enquire.js in a <script> tag via the offical cdn link the above code works now.

Comment: may be because you imported as `Enquire` and use it as `enquire`?